# Trigger Flow from Change Data Capture Event (CDC)

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, platform-event, change-data-capture

Can Salesforce Flows listen to Change Data Capture events like Apex Triggers? I couldn't find anything related on the Web and couldn't make it work in my org.

In case I can't I would like to understand why. If a trigger can, why not a flow?!

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not available.  It seems that if you want to do something similar with flow you can use flow triggers.  But I understand that this is not an ideal answer.  Currently only platform events.  You could potentially be able to create something similar that is triggered through apex triggers by using

```
Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
inputs.put('Account', myAccount);
  
Flow.Interview.Account_Data_Capture cdcFlow = 
  new Flow.Interview.Account_Data_Capture (inputs);
cdcFlow.start();
```